# When the API's input only receive sql query string

Tags: .net, api

Recently,My colleague wanna design an API for different Web Server(.net、java、android) to obtain the data they want,it's a .NET API project by the way.

But the API only receive the SQL query string...I feel the API's client will in the trouble soon.

The purpose of the API I thought is that don't let the client worry about 'How should we create the DAL ?','What the relation of the table is in database?'.The client should not worry about those,just pass the parameters into the API,then you will get all the data you want.

And I don't think so the parameters will be the SQL query string.If I must pass the SQL query string into the API,why I don't just use the ADO or EF directly to obtain the data by myself ?My Web Server's framework is ASP.NET.

Why the API exist ?Because the manager want a DAL(BO)to obtain the data and the DAL(BO) must also work with the JAVA team's Web Server.

Here is the simple architecture.

client---Web Server---API---Database

Am I wrong ??Is the pass the SQL query string into the API method not so bad ??What is the disadvantage ??

Answer (score 2):

Sending the SQL query string to an API to retrieve data is the worst idea in the world.

So basically if someone hacks your system you have written them a nice API for your database.

If you're going to do this then you might as well just expose your databases connection method directly. No need for an API. TERRIBLE IDEA!!!

Develop the API to do the work you want. And if you require it to be changed then change it.

**EDIT:**

If they want the flexibility to modify the data being returned then they can send the name of a stored procedure or view to the API instead. The API can then query the database with the stored procedure or view after validating it.

Then they can then add, remove or modify the stored procedures and views in the database without exposing any major security issues.

Comment: Yeah He consider the security so anyone who wanna access the API must get the token first.Is it better??

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure. Always think "what if"!. If you lose security then you WILL lose all of your data either by theft or deletion. If you lose security in a correct implementation then you have still limited the actions that the intruder can perform.